# AAC and naudio sampling rate mismatch

Tags: c#, streaming, naudio

I am streaming audio in C# via naudio running in a separate thread fed via a threadsafe queue. Input into naudio is a stream consisting of 16 bit PCM data, AAC decoded by libfaad2 with PInvoke, as I did not find a native C# AAC decoder. The data consists of a continuous stream originating from live "dab plus" broadcasting sources.

This works all very nice and smooth, with one little exception. The data rates reported by the AAC decoder and naudio do not match. As an example, the libfaad2 decoder reports 48000 Hz sampling rate, having been initialized with the metadata of the broadcast station. NAudio - initialized with this sampling rate -  generates a "Buffer full" exception after a short time (30 sec with 512000bytes naudio buffer, the timeout scaling linearly with the buffer size).

The "DiscardOnBufferOverflow" option of naudio is not a viable solution of the problem, as it causes - of course - audible artifacts after that event. 
When I increase for naudio the reported 48000 Hz by 3000, i.e. initialize the naudio with 51000 Hz, it runs for almost an hour before the buffer overflow exception.

I also recorded a three minutes file with naudio left at 48kHz, sounding perfect.

**My question**: What might be the reason of the bitrate mismatch between naudio and the AAC decoder when streaming? I really would like to know the reason for this, as I do not want to leave the current hack implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although almost 2 years old, the reason for the behaviour had not been resolved, until I found a solution today.

The reason is the behaviour of the libfaad2.dll, which converts the AAC coded buffers to pcm16 buffers. Initialized by its "NeAACDecInit" API call (DTS headers), it assumes frame lengths of 1024 bytes, whereas the DAB+ data are coded with 960 bytes. Nevertheless, the libfaad decodes it, leading to the mentioned mismatch.
The normal solution is to use the "Audio Specific Coding (ASC)" and the "NeAACDecInit2" API call, as is usually applied in DAB+ decoding software. The "Init2" using ASC coding has an option to select the frame length, in contrast to the "Init", using DTS headers, silently assuming the 1024 byte frame length.

However, it is well possible to modify the libfaad "NeAACDecInit" API call with an additional parameter and using it to command libfaad to use the short frame length. Probably the right place to do this in the libfaad2 library would be the file "decoder.c", around line 321, and insert `hDecoder->frameLength = 960;`.

NAudio won't complain any more.

Answer (score 0):

Sample rate is measured in Hz not bps. Are you sure that the AAC is 48kHz or maybe its 48kbps? In which case the sample rate could be 44.1kHz which could account for the difference.

to debug this, I'd write some of the output from libfaad2 to a 48kHz WAV file and check that it plays at expected speed.

Comment: Mark, many thanks for your fast reply! Sorry for the Hz-bps confusion. Of course, the sampling rates are Hz. I edited the question accordingly. The dab plus system generates four possible sampling rates, 16, 24, 32, and 48 kHz (see standard ETSI TS 102 563 V 1.2.1 of 2010) , the one being used is reported in the metadata of the stream (see Table 2 in the document). As I wrote in my question, I had already realized your suggestion to record a file with naudio at 48kHz sampling rate: The file contains 3 1/2 minutes of perfect classical music, without any audible errors.

Comment: could it just be that the NAudio playback is getting behind, and inserting silence causing the buffer to slowly over-fill? Only other explanation I can think of is that playback device isn't really operating at 48kHz.

Comment: In case the naudio inserted silence, would this not show up as gaps in the stream? And an inaccuracy in the playback device (new laptop quadcore i7) should also show up when playing the file with the Win10 media player? I will try to record the aac output  to a file of sufficient size and stream it from that file to naudio, in an isolated application. Probably your guess that it is a realtime issue might point into the right direction.